# Trouble installing ZSH

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I did the following:

```
yum install zsh
```

Then

```
chsh eduar  
New shell [/bin/bash]: /bin/zsh
```

When I type:

```
curl -L http://install.ohmyz.sh | sh
```

I got this:

```
You already have Oh My Zsh installed.
You'll need to  remove /home/eduar/.oh-my-zsh if you want to install
```

It says that I already have installed the module.
Then, our last step is to reload our resources file:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Here I have the following issue:

```
bash: /home/eduar/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh: line 26: syntax error near unexpected token `('  
bash: /home/eduar/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh: line 26: `for config_file ($ZSH/lib/*.zsh); do'
```

If y restart the terminal, it seems like ZSH is not working.

Comment: your last message has `bash`, try to log out and log back in, dont use `source` as that's part of `bash` and `zsh` is _ALREADY_ installed on your system, you can verify by `rpm -q zsh`.

Comment: Typing rpm -q zsh got:  zsh-5.0.7-7.fc21.x86_64

Comment: Just want to add to @alexus comment, that closing the terminal and opening it up won't help much because it is the same session on the computer (meaning, X session). You just need to log out and then log in. In case it's a remote server, just open a new SSH connection.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your `yum install zsh` went through without any errors, `zsh` is installed on your system, you can verify it by `rpm -q zsh`.

- `chsh - change your login shell`, you need to *LOGIN* to your system.
- `source` is part of `bash`, so you cannot use it for that.
- `curl | sh` says zsh installed, not some module

error has `bash` in it, that should raise a flag for you as you're not on `zsh`. try just typing `zsh` if you don't want to relogin.

Try following:

```
$ zsh
$ rm /home/eduar/.oh-my-zsh
$ curl -L https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh | sh
```